# Creating a tumbling windows in python

Tags: python, numpy

Just wondering if there is a way to construct a tumbling window in python. So for example if I have list/ndarray , `listA = [3,2,5,9,4,6,3,8,7,9]`. Then how could I find the maximum of the first 3 items (3,2,5) -> 5, and then the next 3 items (9,4,6) -> 9 and so on... Sort of like breaking it up to sections and finding the max. So the final result would be list `[5,9,8,9]`

Comment: yep it did worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1:** One-liner for windowed-max using [`np.maximum.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) -

```
In [118]: np.maximum.reduceat(listA,np.arange(0,len(listA),3))
Out[118]: array([5, 9, 8, 9])
```

Becomes more compact with `np.r_` -

```
np.maximum.reduceat(listA,np.r_[:len(listA):3])
```

**Approach #2:** Generic ufunc way

Here's a function for generic ufuncs and that window length as a parameter -

```
def windowed_ufunc(a, ufunc, W):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    n = len(a)
    L = W*(n//W)
    out = ufunc(a[:L].reshape(-1,W),axis=1)
    if n>L:
        out = np.hstack((out, ufunc(a[L:])))
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [81]: a = [3,2,5,9,4,6,3,8,7,9]

In [82]: windowed_ufunc(a, ufunc=np.max, W=3)
Out[82]: array([5, 9, 8, 9])
```

On other ufuncs -

```
In [83]: windowed_ufunc(a, ufunc=np.min, W=3)
Out[83]: array([2, 4, 3, 9])

In [84]: windowed_ufunc(a, ufunc=np.sum, W=3)
Out[84]: array([10, 19, 18,  9])

In [85]: windowed_ufunc(a, ufunc=np.mean, W=3)
Out[85]: array([3.33333333, 6.33333333, 6.        , 9.        ])
```

---

**Benchmarking**

Timings on NumPy solutions on array data with sample data scaled up by `10000x` -

```
In [159]: a = [3,2,5,9,4,6,3,8,7,9]

In [160]: a = np.tile(a, 10000)

# @yatu's soln
In [162]: %timeit moving_maxima(a, w=3)
435 µs ± 8.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# From this post - app#1
In [167]: %timeit np.maximum.reduceat(a,np.arange(0,len(a),3))
353 µs ± 2.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# From this post - app#2
In [165]: %timeit windowed_ufunc(a, ufunc=np.max, W=3)
379 µs ± 6.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Would there be a way to place the maximums in an array the same size as the original array? For example: array;(2,5,6,7,4,2)... pulling the maximums from every 3 would create an array (6,7). But how could we create an array that looks like (0,0,6,7,0,0)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner, you can use list comprehension:

```
listA = [3,2,5,9,4,6,3,8,7,9]
listB=[max(listA[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(listA),3)]
print (listB)
```

it returns:

```
[5, 9, 8, 9]
```

Of course the codes can be written more dynamically: if you want a different window size, just change `3` to any integer.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy, you can extend the list with zeroes so its length is divisible by the window size, and reshape and compute the `max`along the second axis:

```
def moving_maxima(a, w):
    mod = len(a)%w
    d = w if mod else mod
    x = np.r_[a, [0]*(d-mod)]
    return x.reshape(-1,w).max(1)
```

---

Some examples:

```
moving_maxima(listA,2)
# array([3., 9., 6., 8., 9.])

moving_maxima(listA,3)
#array([5, 9, 8, 9])

moving_maxima(listA,4)
#array([9, 8, 9])
```